# Is it possible to disable reordering a single item in a reorderable listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, drag-and-drop, reorderlist, reorderable-list

I am trying to create a ListView that meets the following criteria:

1. The items in the ListView are categorized into sections with headers for each section
2. The items can be dragged from one section to another
3. The section headers are not draggable

This would easy to accomplish if [ReorderableListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html) allowed you to disable a ListTile from being dragged & dropped (in other words, I would be able to create the headers as ListTile items in the ListView and disable dragging and dropping on only them while still allowing everything else to be dragged & dropped), but I can't figure out how. Any tips?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/drag_and_drop_lists This plugin will help you

Comment: I have the same requirements as you did. Did you manage to get anywhere with that?

Answer (score 8):

This is another workaround.

Wrap the widget you don't want to be moved in a GestureDetector, then override the onLongPress.

```
 return GestureDetector(
                                  onLongPress: () {},
                                  key: ValueKey(index),
                                  child: Column(
                                      children: List.generate(
                                          3,
                                          (index) => ListTile(
                                              title: Text("TItle test")))),
                                );
```

Check this [https://github.com/hanshengchiu/reorderables/issues/89#:~:text=movable%20widgets%20in%3A-,GestureDetector(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20onLongPress%3A%20()%20%7B%7D%2C%20//%20Override%20onLongPress%20to%20make%20item%20unmovable.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20...%0A),-6](https://github.com/hanshengchiu/reorderables/issues/89#:%7E:text=movable%20widgets%20in%3A-,GestureDetector(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20onLongPress%3A%20()%20%7B%7D%2C%20//%20Override%20onLongPress%20to%20make%20item%20unmovable.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20child%3A%20...%0A),-6) for the full discussion

Answer (score 4):

Just discovered the [AbsorbPointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AbsorbPointer-class.html) and [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) classes.

Comment: This will still allow items to be reordered around it. So if you were trying to keep an item at the top, they could drag another above it.

Comment: That's a valid observation. With this implementation, I think the the simplest solution to this edge case is to ignore the invalid reordering in the onReorder callback

But I agree that an ideal implementation would prevent the top header from moving when reordering an item above it

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent moving the headers with `AbsortPointer` etc. as you mentioned, but if the other items are moved into a place that you don't want to allow, you can simply check for this in the `onReorder` callback and not update the underlying model, so when the user drops the item it will get back to its original place. E.g. if the user tries moving any movable item to be placed before the first header, you detect this (newIndex == 0) and return early.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ReorderableDragStartListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ReorderableDragStartListener-class.html).

Wrap the sections that need to be non-reorderable with it and pass `enabled: false` like so:

```
class HeaderSection extends StatelessWidget {
  const HeaderSection({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableDragStartListener(
      index: index,
      enabled: false,
      child: const Text('This header can not be dragged'),
    );
  }
}
```

There is also [ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ReorderableDelayedDragStartListener-class.html) for cases where you want to use long-press to begin reordering.

Comment: This did not work for me on flutter 3.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a some type of nonreorderable bool field to tiles , and check it when onReorder is called, and just skip the index change, or do same extra logic for that particular case.

Answer (score -1):

**The reorderable list wrap with AbsorbPointer widget**

Use AbsorbPointer to disable widgets

```
 AbsorbPointer(
            absorbing: countList.length <= 1 ? true : false,
            child: ReorderableListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                buildDefaultDragHandles: false,
                dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: <Widget>[
                  for (var i = 0; i < countList.length; i++)
                    Card(
                      elevation: 0,
                      color: customColors().backgroundPrimary,
                      key: ValueKey(
                          countList[i].Name),
                      child: Container(
                        child:Text("Demo")
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
                onReorder:onReoder),
          ),
```